# Finding all graphs with a given automorphism group on $n$ vertices

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Is there a way to algorithmically find all graphs that have a certain automorphism group on $n$ vertices? For example, is there a way to find all graphs with automorphism group $A_5$ on $1000$ vertices? Obviously you could look at all graphs, and then compute the automorphism group of each graph, but this is very inefficient.

I would also be interested in a way to count the number of graphs with a given automorphism group, or to generate (or count) all graphs that have an automorphism group of a certain order. Special cases (e.g. trivial automorphism group) would be interesting as well.

Clearly the only graph on $n$ vertices with automorphism group $S_n$ is $K_n$.

Comment: The discrete graph also has group $S_n$.

Comment: Johnson graphs also have automorphism group $S_n$ (most of the time).

Comment: @SteveD they do not have $n$ vertices in general, though.